# Теория алгоритмов.

Tags: алгоритм

Какие разделы математики нужны чтобы приступить к теории алгоритмов, то есть там, где надо оценивать алгоритм (например, O(N))?

Comment: Начала анализа, дискретная математика, комбинаторика. Глава о сложности есть в большинстве книг по алгоритмам.

Comment: А в дискретке что следует учить: теорию множеств, графы, булева алгебра и на сколько?

Comment: Вообще это слишком общее понятие, туда и комбинаторика входит, и анализ алгоритмов. По большому счёту, обо всех разделах нужно хотя бы иметь представление.

Comment: Зависит от оцениваемого алгоритма. Для некоторых хватает знаний школьной арифметики :)

Comment: Дональд Кнут "Искусство программирования". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Искусство_программирования

Comment: Кнута смотрел, 1 том еще нормально, дальше уже плохо, там уже идет какая-то узкоспециализированная математика.

Comment: Вообще это очень похоже на справочник, там теории не особо много, а по сложности Дональд Кнут - это уже уровень Гришки Перльмана

Comment: Попроще - "Левитин, Алгоритмы", например